# No such file or directory when attempting to execute subprocess call

Tags: python

**Preface:** I understand this question has been asked before, but I cannot find a solution to my error from looking at those previous answers.

All I want to do is call `diff` for the output of two different commands on the same file.

```
 import os, sys
 from subprocess import check_call
 import shlex

 ourCompiler = 'espressoc';
 checkCompiler = 'espressocr';

 indir = 'Tests/Espresso/GoodTests';

 check_call(["pwd"]);

 for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
     for f in filenames:
         if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == f:
             str1 = "<(./%s ./%s) " % (ourCompiler, os.path.join(root, f))
             str2 = "<(./%s ./%s) " % (checkCompiler, os.path.join(root, f))
             check_call(["diff", str1, str2])
```

Why is it that I receive following error?

```
diff: <(./espressoc ./Tests/Espresso/GoodTests/Init.java) : No such file or directory
diff: <(./espressocr ./Tests/Espresso/GoodTests/Init.java) : No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runTest.py", line 21, in <module>
    check_call(["diff", str1, str2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['diff', '<(./espressoc ./Tests/Espresso/GoodTests/Init.java) ', '<(./espressocr ./Tests/Espresso/GoodTests/Init.java) ']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

If I were to run this command from my shell it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` is complaining that it can't find the file with the strange name `<(./espressoc ./Tests/Espresso/GoodTests/Init.java)` because that's the argument you fed it.

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (`check_call` is a convenience function for it)  is *directly* calling what you give it, there **isn't a shell** to interpret redirections or anything, unless you tell it `shell=True`, which will then call the command via `/bin/sh` (on POSIX). Note the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) before using it.

So basically:

```
subprocess.check_call(['diff', '<this', '<that'])` # strange files.
subprocess.check_call('diff <this <that', shell=True)` # /bin/sh does some redirection
```

If you wanted to be "pure" (probably more effort than it's worth), I think you could subprocess all three processes (diff, compiler 1 and 2) and handle the piping yourself. Does `diff` wait for 2 EOFs or something before closing stdin? Not sure how it actually deals with the double input redirection like your line has...